# Bookmaker quotes pay off odds of 99 to 1 against a particular horse

Tags: probability, gambling

> If a bookmaker quotes pay off odds of $99$ to $1$ against a particular horse winning a race, does that suggest that the chance that the horse will win is $\frac{1}{100}$, less than $\frac{1}{100}$ or more than $\frac{1}{100}$?

---

I tried doing this on my own but saying "Oh it's subjective so it depends on whether or not we trust the bookmaker's intuition" and then I realized I was messing up the definitions between chance and odds. Can someone please help me this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Bookmaking and probability are not the same thing. Take a look at this. http://www.sfu.ca/~apavlov/Econ/Rennie%20Baxter%20(1996)%20Parable%20of%20the%20Bookmaker.pdf

Comment: Keep in mind that the bookie will want to expect to make a profit.  If the bookie was being perfectly fair and bases his calculation off of the horses' performance and not off of other factors (such as people's betting patterns), and the *actual odds* that the horse wins is 99 to 1 against, then yes the probability would be $1/100$.  Since the bookie wants to make money, we can safely assume the actual probability is less than that.

Comment: Conversely, bookies are generally risk averse: if *nobody* takes the unfavored bet (or everybody does), the bookie is going to pay a lot of money out of his pocket if everyone wins. In this case, odds need to be adjusted to prevent the impact of such a "run on the bank."

Answer (score 1):

odds against = unfavorable occurrences : favorable occurrences,

whereas probability = favorable occurrences / total occurrences,

thus odds against of $\;99:1 = \dfrac1{99+1} = \dfrac1{100}$

Comment: The above, of course is true only if it is a **fair bet.** In any case, in horse racing, the probability is an *estimated* one, not one mathematically computable, as in roulette, say.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmakers adjust the odds so as to make a profit regardless of who wins. Typically less than 90% of the money bet is paid back. If 30% has been bet on one horse, they may offer 3 to 1 on it. If the proportion of money bet on it increases before the race, they will lower its odds. The odds reflect what other bettors have been thinking, up to that point in time.

Answer (score -1):

99 to 1 odds just means money is staked more in favor of other horses.  This does not necessarily reflect the actual probability of a horse winning a race.

If you assumed the odds were a literal interpretation of the actual statistical outcome then 99 to 1 would mean 1/100 probability.  
1/100 **=** 1/100

You can find more info here about it in the link below.

[Odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds)

Comment: $99$ to $1$ odds against corresponds to a probability of $\frac{1}{100}$

Comment: 99 to 1 is even one of the examples listed in the link you provided.  Perhaps it might be worth reading yourself before posting.